# Notifications not showing up on database trigger

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am using firebase cloud functions for sending notifications to users when database trigger is called.The registration token is saved in firebase database. The problem is that inspite of registration tokens getting saved, the notifications are not showing up in these devices. 
This is **index.js**

```
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);



exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Blog').onWrite(event => {
const title = event.data.child('title').val();

const token_no = event.data.child('token_no').val();


  const getDeviceTokensPromise = admin.database().ref(`/Token/${token_no}`).once('value');
  const getBody=admin.database().ref(`/Blog`).once('value');

  return Promise.all([getDeviceTokensPromise,getBody]).then(results => {
    const tokensSnapshot = results[0];
    const notify=results[1];




    if (!tokensSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
      return console.log('There are no notification tokens to send to.');
    }
    console.log('There are', tokensSnapshot.numChildren(), 'tokens to send notifications to.');


    // Notification details.
    const payload = {
      notification: {
        title: 'You have a new Alert!',
        body: `${notify.child('title').val()}`,

      }
    };

    // Listing all tokens.
    const tokens = Object.keys(tokensSnapshot.val());

    // Send notifications to all tokens.
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload).then(response => {
      // For each message check if there was an error.
      const tokensToRemove = [];
      response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
        const error = result.error;
        if (error) {
          console.error('Failure sending notification to', tokens[index], error);
          // Cleanup the tokens who are not registered anymore.
          if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' ||
              error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
            tokensToRemove.push(tokensSnapshot.ref.child(tokens[index]).remove());
          }
        }
      });
      return Promise.all(tokensToRemove);
    });
  });
});
```

Database snapshot:

```
"Token" : {
"token_no" : {
  "ctxjePemYZE:APA91bFJXXyTkyvXOlSY...4VbWu7Vbf7itwbwZu9umSvg_tdB1lKD1d8g" : "true",
  "dgVszInjIW0:APA91bFZE3Av5unZTgp...RUeYb-CUhWjO1otqguhE9NTQZ8XgK6nRIW5" : "true"
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

**Update 2:**

Your code uses `Object.keys(tokensSnapshot.val())` to get the tokens.  That means the tokens must be the keys under `token_no`, not the values.  Like this:

```
"Token" : {
  "-KoWsMn9rCIitQeNvixr" : {
    "dK1FjGbNr6k:APA91b...S8JK2d69JpO" : "123" // token is the key, value is not significant; could be "123", true, or 0.
  },
  ...
}
```

**Update:**

You should review the [documentation for the **Event** parameter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.Event) of a database trigger to get a better understanding of the `params` and `data` properties.  `params` provide acces to the wildcards in the trigger reference, `data` is the snapshot.  In your code, you want to get values from the snapshot.

Add these changes:

```
const title = event.data.child('title').val();
const desp = event.data.child('desp').val();
const token_no = event.data.child('token_no').val()

const payload = {
  notification: {
    title: 'You have a new Alert!',
    body: `${Post.child('title').val()}`,  // <= CHANGED
    //icon: follower.photoURL
  }
};
```

Running the code you posted, with these changes, I am able to send and receive a notification.

There are two problems.  The first is this statement:

```
const getDeviceTokensPromise = admin.database().ref(`/Token/{token_no}`).once('value');
```

`token_no` is not defined.  And when you do define it and want to substitute its value, you will need to add a `$`:

```
`/Token/${token_no}`
```

The second problem is that `Post` is not defined, which causes function execution to fail.  Check your function logs:

```
const payload = {
  notification: {
    title: 'You have a new Alert!',
    body: `${Post.title}`,
    //icon: follower.photoURL
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you please check if the code is correct or not as I have little knowledge about javascript. Also after running the edited code, it gets executed but the log of cloud functions says "There are no notification tokens to send to." ,but the tokens are getting saved in database. I am not sure where the code is wrong.

Comment: It is still the same! It is still showing in the log that there are no tokens. We have to create the FirebaseInstanceId to generate the tokens, right? Or index.js will do it automatically?

Comment: Each instance of your app must store its token using (e.g.) `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()` and store it in the database.

Comment: I did that too. But the log is showing that there is no token.

Comment: The situation is still the same. I have updated the code and the database snapshot too. Let me know if I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: The posted code works for me.  Send a notification to your device from the Firebase console to confirm that your receive code is working.

Comment: YA it is working if I send notifications from the console. Then where must be the problem if I use cloud functions?